# Share Internet Connection With Symbian device, no, not the other way around

Tags: tethering

I do not have data on my phone, and I was wondering if anyone out there knew how I would go about sharing my laptop's internet connection with my Symbian s60v5fp3 phone.  How can I do such a thing?

Comment: Does your phone have Wifi?

Answer (score 2):

Try GnuBox on phone (works via bluetooth).
But if your phone supports Wifi, buy cheap router (like DIR-300), it will be much faster.

Comment: It will allow me to have my phone get to the internet through my laptop, yes?

Comment: Yes, sure. http://xan.dnsalias.org/gnubox/

Comment: How can i use it with s60 fp5 on my nokia 5230?